# Custom Form Validation Is Not Working For Some Reason

Tags: php, laravel

I am using custom form validation for my replies using [toastr](https://github.com/yoeunes/toastr). For some reason the validation does indeed kick in by displaying the toastr notification [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nfUw.png). But it won't stop the user from creating a reply.

I've tried overriding stock validation functions such as:
`formatValidationErrors()` and `failedValidation()`
The second function was the only one to work (displays the toastr notification), but it gave me the issue above.

App\Http\Controllers\ReplyController.php

Here is the store method.
The `ThreadReceivedReply` event is included at the top of the file.

```
public function store(Thread $thread, ReplyForm $form)
{
    if (Gate::denies('create', new Reply)) {
        toastr()->error('You are creating too many replies. Please wait 30 seconds', 'Slow Down');
        return back();
    }

    $reply = Reply::create([
        'body' => Purifier::clean(request('body')),
        'user_steamid' => auth()->user()->steamid
    ]);

    event(new ThreadReceivedReply($reply));

    if($reply->user_steamid != $thread->user_steamid) {
        $thread->user->notify(new RepliedToThread($thread));
    };

    $thread->replies()->save($reply);

    Cache::forget('replies');

    toastr()->success('Reply created. Nice job');
    return back();
}
```

App\Http\Forms\ReplyForm.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Forms;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class ReplyForm extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // testing
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'body' => 'required|max:1000|spamfree'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'body.required' => 'Your reply needs body text!'
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {

        $messages = $validator->messages();

        foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
        {
            toastr()->error($message, 'Woops');
        }

        return $validator->errors()->all();
    }
}
```

I was sort of going off of [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/flash-toastr-error-message-if-formrequest-fails?page=1) to try to fix the issue but it didn't get me very far.
The expected outcome is when you don't input body information it will display that validation error as a toast. I would show you errors but none were displayed. If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask me. Thank's for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you show your controller

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I just edited the post